# Compound ffmpeg commands stored in a variable is not executed correctly

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, debian

Following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#-_-_-_--- CONFIGURATION ---_-_-_-

CAMERA_COUNT=2
SRC_WIDTH=320
SRC_HEIGHT=240
MARGIN=320

#-_-_-_--- END CONFIGURATION---_-_-_-

CHARS=( {A..Z} )
FULL_WIDTH=$((SRC_WIDTH * CAMERA_COUNT))

FFMPEG="ffmpeg "

for ((i = 0; i < CAMERA_COUNT; i++))
do
        FFMPEG+="-f flv -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/PanoView${CHARS[i]} "
done

FFMPEG+="-filter_complex \"nullsrc=size=$((SRC_WIDTH * CAMERA_COUNT))x${SRC_HEIGHT} [base]; [base][0:v] overlay [tmp1]; "

for ((i = 1; i < CAMERA_COUNT - 1; i++))
do
        FFMPEG+="[tmp${i}][${i}:v] overlay=x=$((SRC_WIDTH * i)) [tmp$((i + 1))];"
done

FFMPEG+="[tmp$((CAMERA_COUNT - 1))][$((CAMERA_COUNT - 1)):v] overlay=x=$((SRC_WIDTH * (CAMERA_COUNT - 1)))\" -f flv -b:v 1M -an -r 25 rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/test"

$FFMPEG

echo $FFMPEG
```

The output of the last echo:

```
ffmpeg -f flv -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/PanoViewA -f flv -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/PanoViewB -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=640x240 [base]; [base][0:v] overlay [tmp1]; [tmp1][1:v] overlay=x=320" -f flv -b:v 1M -an -r 25 rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/test
```

When I execute the compound command in the FFMPEG variable in the script, I get the error message:

> [AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fffed837620] No such filter: '"nullsrc'
>
> Error initializing complex filters.
>
> Invalid argument

However, if I copy the composite code, which I have the script output at the end, paste it and execute it, everything works as expected. What could be the reason?

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: So this just doesn't work, because of the WordSplitting. Let me get this straight.  And I thought I could simplify the whole thing, because I often have to jump between the source number, sometimes 6 cameras, sometimes only 2, sometimes 8. thanks for the answer! I don't usually write scripts, that was really just so I could make it easier with switching. So sorry, if that was quite a beginner question ^^.

Comment: Found a solution by the way. You can call the variable like: eval $FFMPEG
That's working